# How to ignore all whitespace characters and punctuations in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The below query working for one string. However when I run at whole table data it's not working

```
select
   lower( regexp_replace( nvl(column1,':'), '\\s+|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+', '')) as addres_line_1,
   column1 
from values('122 E 7th Street ');
```

output: `122e7thstreet`

when I run similar query for the table, the white spaces are not fully removed.
output: `122e7th street`

table level query:

```
select concat(
        column1, ':',
        column2, ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(nvl(ADDRESS_LINE_1,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+',''),'[ \t\r\n\v\f]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(ADDRESS_LINE_2,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(ADDRESS_LINE_3,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(PRIMARY_TOWN,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(COUNTRY,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(TERRITORY_CODE,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(POSTAL_CODE,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+|\\s+','')), ':',
        lower(regexp_replace(nvl(COUNTRY_CODE,':'),'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+',''))
    ) as  ROLE_PLAYER_ADDRESS_HASH_KEY1 
from address
```

Answer (score 2):

Does using regex expressions like this one work work:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(ADDRESS_LINE_1, '[^\\w]'),'_')
```

\w is any digit, letter, or underscore - hence the need for an outer REGEXP_REPLACE to remove underscores

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(ADDRESS_LINE_1, '[^\\w]'),'_').This syntax removing additional special characters. The requirement is to remove only whitespace and punctuations only.For example überseering 10 here we need to keep ü.

Answer (score 1):

So you have three different regex,

you single demostraition regex is:

```
'\\s+|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+'
```

then you use:

```
'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+'
```

for the table except for `POSTAL_CODE` which uses:

```
'\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+|\\s+'
```

Thus do they work equally well on you example input, or other inputs you see failure on?

```
select 
    '\\s+|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+' as reg_1,
    '\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+' as reg_2,
    '\\s|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+|\\s+' as reg3,
    lower( regexp_replace( nvl(column1,':'), reg_1, '')) as addres_1,
    lower( regexp_replace( nvl(column1,':'), reg_2, '')) as addres_2,
    lower( regexp_replace( nvl(column1,':'), reg3, '')) as addres_3,
    column1 
from values
    ('122 E 7th Street '),
    ('122 E 7th Street  '),
    ('  122 E 7th Street  ')
    -- etc, etc
;
```

alrighty, so the token you have is C2 A0 `\u00a0` the no-break-space token.

```
select 
    '\\s+|[][!"#$%&\'()*+,.\\\\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+' as reg_1,
    column1,
    regexp_replace( column1, reg_1, '') as out
from values
('122 e 7th\u00a0street')
```

gives:

```
REG_1: \s+|[][!"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@^_`{|}~-]+ 
COLUMN1: 122 e 7th street
OUT: 122e7th street
```

and if you copy that output the space has converted to a normal 0x20 space.

So now we know what the input data is we just need to match it.

so you can use the TRANSLATE function to remove the unicode character via

```
select 
    column1
    ,regexp_replace( column1, '\\s+', '') as r1
    ,translate(column1,'\u00a0',' ') as t1 as t1
    ,regexp_replace( t1, '\\s+', '') as r
from values ('122 e 7th\u00a0street');
```

which means we can just put \u00a0 into the regex

```
regexp_replace( column1, '\\s+|\u00a0+', '')
```

works a charm!

Comment: the above query is working when we pass the values manually, however when you run the query on table it is not removing the whitespace after 7th.  Please see below output.

Comment: the above query is working when we pass the values manually, however when you run the query on table it is not removing the whitespace after 7th.  Please see below output.                                   122e7th street  122e7th street  122e7th street                                                                                     when i open the above output in notepad++ and give encoding as ansi                                           122e7thÂ streetÂ  122e7thÂ streetÂ  122e7thÂ streetÂ

Comment: At one level this is meaningful details that should have been added to the original description. It sound like given you have Unicode data, that maybe you are getting impacted by Collation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html

Comment: it would make sense to actually get a badly match "string" with unicode, base64 encode it, and then show us that, then the exact unicode tokens can be seen, and snowflake regex with the actual misbehaving string can be given instead of talking about string that don't have your problem. And us guessing at the problem.

Comment: can you please provide the syntax to get the string into unicode,base 64 in snowflake.the default format is utf8

Comment: yes, base64 the utf8, utf8 is the objective. the regex run on the utf8 tokens, so an extended utf8 token, will be part of the match pattern requirements. The reason for want the base64 of the utf, is some there is not "mapping" happening in a cut'n'paste process.

Comment: @Nagendra I pulled the asni output `122e7thÂ streetÂ 122e7thÂ streetÂ 122e7thÂ streetÂ`, and pasted into notepad++ as asni, and then looked at hex of the file, the `Â` is the utf-8 one more byte marker, thus what the "space" is in ansi is not printing, but it is not a valid space, because the seconds values are in the range x80 to xbf. purhaps it is `c2 ad SOFT HYPHEN`? ether way, until is known, it makes it hard to filter, will keep looking.